# PHP strpos not working on substrings?

Tags: php, strpos

I am stuck on this and need help...
I have a string like this one: VG412-FR-B5W20X24

I am getting different results when using `strpos()` in PHP5.6 if I am searching for a single char or a substring:

```
var_dump(strpos("VG412-FR-B5W20X24","FR")); // output: bool(false) 
var_dump(strpos("VG412-FR-B5W20X24","F")); // output: int(13)
```

note that both F and FR are present in the string but one evaluates as an int with location 13 and the other evaluates to false...

can anyone help or have an idea how I can find the location of the substring?

Comment: `var_dump(strpos("VG412-FR-B5W20X24","FR"));` gives me `6` (PHP 5.6)

Comment: They both show `int(6)` https://3v4l.org/9OZtc

Comment: What charset are those strings? Are they a dual-byte charset (with a null byte between each value byte)? That would be my guess if the first returns false, and the second is showing offset 13 rather than offset 6

Comment: Hi guys, I found the issue. I was passing the value from a file and the file was encoded wrong (instead of a TXT it was TXT Unicode) . This what caused this issue... lost 24 hours of my life on this but I guess this is how you learn best :) Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Works in my PHP 5.5.9 environment.

Try using `mb_strpos` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php instead.

If that doesn't work can you attach output from your `php -i`?